# Why does it take about 5 minutes for a transaction to register on the network?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, monero-wallet-gui

I've noticed that a transaction will not register in a receiver's wallet for about 5 minutes after being sent. In Bitcoin, it is registered immediately and then you wait for confirmations. My question is not about waiting for confirmations in order to unlock balance, but about the simple "registering" that a transfer was sent. Does anybody know why we have this delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fresh transactions go into the mempool before they get mined into a block.
Current version of Monero-wallet-gui (and also monero-wallet-cli) does not scan the mempool for incoming transactions, therefore the transaction needs to be included into a block first so the reciver is able to see it.

This will be different in the new Version, where monero-wallet-gui is able to scan the mempool directly, which will make transactions visible after seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Transactions that are not yet included in a block are stored in the memory pool. When you submit a transaction to the network, you'll almost immediately see your transaction stored in the memory pool on a blockchain explorer, e.g. http://explore.moneroworld.com . Average block time is 2 minutes, so the newly created outputs will be unlocked roughly after 22 minutes (for 10 confirmations).

Comment: Ok thanks, but why is the trx not immediately visible by the receiver like with Bitcoin?

Comment: I've used only Copay as a Bitcoin wallet, and I guess the wallet just shows the incoming coins simply when it finds them on the memory pool.

Comment: The GUI wallet will have this feature soon
https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/pull/397

Comment: @jaquee Great, looking forward to it!

Comment: @kenshi84 what is the memory pool?  Is it possible that my daemon is not completely up to date although it is running and this causes the delay? Thanx.

Comment: The memory pool is a temporary storage buffer held by each daemon. Newly broadcasted transactions are relayed among nodes and kept in their memory pools, which happens quite quickly. After making a transaction, you can see it almost immediately on your daemon's mempool by issuing `print_tx <transaction_hash>` to your daemon.